# Drop shadow for drawLine

Tags: android

I was wondering, usually, how you guy drop shadow for line drawn from `Paint.drawLine`? As I realize `Paint.setShadowLayer` only has effect on `Paint.drawText`, but not `Paint.drawLine`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd draw a second line, shifted by 1px to the right and 1px to the bottom (or more, depends on the "shadow distance" you want to achieve)

1, 1 since the light is normally expected to come from the top left corner (as a default in our brain).

You could achieve different light positions by setting different values for these offsets.

I'd draw it with a black color and an opacity of 50% (just to say - must tune it case by case, depending on the background).